# Node.js get MAX-VALUE of new Set()

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I get the maximum possible size of a new Set() in Node.js Javascript?

```
let mySet = new Set();
mySet.MAX_VALUE;
```

Only .size is possible as a get size.

Comment: Do you want the count of elements in the set as a size?

Comment: I can call mySet.size and get the size of mySet. However, .size is not a setter.
I want to know how large mySet can be on my machine. How many elements can mySet store without throwing an error? :)

Comment: Can you check the possible size of an array(ArrayList in other languages)? I don't think so; it depends on how much memory you have available at a certain time and what kind of elements you will store, so It's dynamic. The same with the set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` instances are bounded only by the available memory (or an arbitrary limit imposed by the environment). There's no specified way to determine that limit (if, in fact, it can even be described in terms of a maximum number of elements).

The `size` property's getter returns a `number`, so in theory if the `Set` had more than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` elements in it, that number could be imprecise. That doesn't necessarily imply that the `Set` can't have that many elements (but that would be a **truly massively large** `Set`). The specification for [`size`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-get-set.prototype.size) has the true count of elements [converted to the `number` type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/notational-conventions.html#%F0%9D%94%BD) at the point of access.

---

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74713553/node-js-get-max-value-of-new-set/74713612#comment131865525_74713553) you've said:

> I want to know how large mySet can be on my machine.

That may depend on what you're putting in the set, but as far as I know, you can only determine that by building a set until adding to it fails.

On my machine using Node v18, I can add `16,777,216` `BigInt` instances to a set before it fails. And I can add exactly that same number of unique objects to it where each object contains a copy of that `BigInt` (that is, a set of larger things), suggesting that Node.js limits the size of the `Set` to that many elements regardless of memory (since neither of those pushes my memory boundaries).

Comment: I have tried and mySet crashed at : 17874629.
Even if I put my maxset size at 17874600 which is smaller I still get a:
    error:RangeError: Set maximum size exceeded

Comment: @ryokan - Okay, so that tells you about where the limit is on your machine.